# NetLogo - Breed and Characteristics

Tags: netlogo

I've a little simulation where zombies and humans fight each other. The code below is the code for creating my zombies.

```
create-zombies 5 [
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      set color black
      set size 2
      set shape "person"
      set zombies_speed 0.5

    ]
```

This code is the code used to turn humans into zombies. The `convert-h` variable is a global variable that i set it to `=` to `convert-h-2` which is a slider that can be used to to determine the probability of humans turning into zombies.

```
to infect
  set convert-h convert-h-2
  if any? humans in-radius 1 [
    ask humans in-radius 1 [ 
      if random 10 < convert-h [ 
        hatch-zombies  1 [
          
          set heading random 360] 
        die]]]
end
```

However when a human turns into a zombie, it doesn't take in all the characteristics of a zombie ( `size 2` `shape "person"`). It only takes the `speed`, `breed` and `color`. Is there a way to add these 2 characteristics of a zombie without having to manually write it in the 2nd code snippet? I hope everything I described makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unify your "zombie setup" logic into a procedure, then call that when they are created and when they infect/hatch:

```
to setup-zombie
  set color black
  set size 2
  set shape "person"
  set zombies_speed 0.5
end

...
  create-zombies 5 [
    setup-zombie
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
...


to infect
  set convert-h convert-h-2
  if any? humans in-radius 1 [
    ask humans in-radius 1 [ 
      if random 10 < convert-h [ 
        hatch-zombies  1 [
          setup-zombie
          set heading random 360] 
        die]]]
end
```